# Combine text from multiple cells into a single cell with multiple mixed delimiters

Tags: google-sheets

Does anyone know a formula to combine several cells into a text in one cell with mixed delimiters between words?

Cell A1 - First Name
Cell B1 - Last Name
Cell C1 - Job Title
Cell D1 - Company

I would like to combine the first two cells with a space and the rest with a comma followed by a space.
My target for the above cells is:

"First Name Last Name, Job Title, Company"

Does anyone know a formula for this please?

Answer (score 7):

```
=A1&" "&B1&", "&C1&", "&D1
```

This will return a string saying:
"First Name Last Name, Job Title, Company"

Answer (score 2):

You could still use the join function for the data, the only change being that for first portion you use the `&` function to achieve the `first name last name` join, then add the remaining array:

```
=JOIN(", ",A1&" "&B1,C1:D1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to merge text with a space for example `A4 = David` & `B4 = Willis` type the following formula to create one cell with David Willis (You will have to re-format the cell after

```
=concatenate(A4," ",B4)
```

Answer (score -2):

I found this article (https://hubpages.com/technology/How-to-combine-rows-in-Google-Spreadsheet) and it was very helpful to us when we together with my team work on the same spreadsheet document and have to combine or merge all our data.

Comment: Hi, could you add a brief summary of the information contained in the link to the body of your answer, please?